# Way to omit undefined preprocessor branches by default with unifdef?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm using a complicated C code that includes many, many compilation options.  This
makes the code very hard to read.  I'd like to produce a copy of the code reflecting
the way it's actually compiled.  I've gotten pretty good results using the "unifdef" 
utility, which I didn't know about until recently.  However, I'm puzzled why it's so hard 
to invoke, and am wondering if I'm missing something.

Consider this example:

```
#ifdef A
  printf("A\n");
#endif
#ifdef B
  printf("B\n");
#endif
```

If you invoke unifdef with "unifdef -DA junk.c", you get:

```
  printf("A\n");
#ifdef B
  printf("B\n");
#endif
```

Because you didn't tell unifdef that B was undefined, it didn't take it out.

I would like the utility to behave such that when I say unifdef -DA, I get instead:

```
  printf("A\n");
```

This would correspond to what the C preprocessor is actually doing: 
whatever branches are undefined are omitted.

To get this behavior with unifdef, I seem to need to use
"unifdef -DA -UB junk.c", explicitly telling it that B is undefined.
Though maybe I missed a simpler way to invoke it.

I wrote a python script to generate the long list of required -D and -U
flags from the  Makefile of the code I'm using (typically 80 per routine).
And the results are excellent.  But I'm wondering whether such a script 
is actually necessary.

It's also possible that another utility (sunifdef? coan?) has my desired behavior
built in already; if so, please mention it.

Comment: If you're using GCC (or similar) and you want to see the result of the preprocessor, just use the `-E` flag.

Comment: I _have_ seen the result of the preprocessor, and believe me, I don't want to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`coan`](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/) utility does what you need with the `-m` flag:

```
$ coan source -DA -m test.c 
  printf("A\n");
```

From the man page:

```
-m, --implicit
    Assume that any symbol that is not --define-ed is implicitly
    --undef-ed.
```

Comment: Thanks.  Will try to take a look at coan.  Need the sysops to install any package on our main cluster, so will mention it as one of the options.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the unifdefall utility which comes with unifdef. See http://dotat.at/prog/unifdef

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to see the code after the pre-processor has ran over it, correct? Then why don't you let the pre-processor run over it and look what output it produces? Just run the compile call using exactly the same arguments you would use when compiling, but add the argument `-E` to it, which means "Do nothing but pre-processing".

```
$ cat preproc.c 
#ifdef A
  printf("A\n");
#endif
#ifdef B
  printf("B\n");
#endif

$ gcc -E preproc.c 
# 1 "preproc.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "preproc.c"

$ gcc -E -DA preproc.c 
# 1 "preproc.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "preproc.c"

  printf("A\n");

$ gcc -E -DB preproc.c
# 1 "preproc.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "preproc.c"




  printf("B\n");

$
```

Comment: No, unifdef is much nicer than running the preprocessor. It does not expand macros, which would make lots of code unreadable. It just collapses ifdefs.

Comment: It also doesn't do the includes, which is nice.

Comment: @detly But those includes may actually contain most of the definitions which are tested throughout the code. If it does not do includes, how would it know about all the `#define` statements in all those includes?

Comment: @Mecki It doesn't interpret any macros other than the ones you specifically mention on the command line.  Apart from the OP's combinatorial problem, this turns out to be exactly what you want when you're refactoring.

Comment: @Zack But according to the OP, this is a project that `includes many, many compilation options` and you want to to specify all those "many, many" options each time on command line? I agree with R.. that it may be a good thing to not always expand macros, but I rather see a disadvantage in not performing includes. If it's just to get rid of the included code, the preprocceor tells you exactly where your file starts; see my answer above, it starts after `# 1 "preproc.c"`, everything before is includes and could easily be stripped if undesired.

Comment: @Mecki - you ask a good question, how do you know something isn't defined in the `#include` files rather than in compile-time flags.  But in this code that isn't how it is set up; I would guess a lot of other codes follow the same pattern.  The results of gcc -E are just unreadable (in the real code, not my toy example) because of macros, and the whole point is to make the code readable.