# How to apply a C preprocessor only to certain (#if/#endif) directives?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I was wondering if it is possible, and if yes how, can I run a **C** preprocessor, like cpp, on a 
C++ source file and only process the conditional directives #if #endif etc. I would like other
directives to stay intact in the output file.

I'm doing some analysis on C# code and there is no C# pre-processor. My idea is to run a **C** preprocessor on C# file and process only conditionals. This way for example, the #region directive, will stay 
in the file, but cpp appears to remove #region.

Comment: C# has `#if` and `#endif` etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Way to omit undefined preprocessor branches by default with unifdef?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491555/way-to-omit-undefined-preprocessor-branches-by-default-with-unifdef)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for a tool like [coan](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/index.php):

> Coan is a software engineering tool for analysing preprocessor-based configurations of C or C++ source code. Its principal use is to simplify a body of source code by eliminating any parts that are redundant with respect to a specified configuration.

It's precisely designed to process `#if` and `#ifdef` preprocessor lines, and remove code accordingly, but it has a lot of other possible uses.

Comment: Excellent! looks exactly like what I'm looking for, but unfortunately it doesn't look like to be available for Mac OS. I'm now trying to see if I can compile it. get some errors. Have you tried it on Mac OS X or do you know of any other alternatives for Mac?

Comment: @Ali, no, I don't have a Mac any more. Sorry. But from the sourceforge page, it looks like the project is active, so you might want to email the developer specifying the compile errors you get. It's not usually too difficult to compile packages for Mac OS X if you have all the prerequisites, fwiw. Good luck.

Comment: It looks like there is an incompatibility with iterator type in one of the classes. I should look into it or contact the developer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The linux unifdef command does what you want:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/unifdef

Even if you're not on linux, there is source available on the web.

BTW, this is a duplicate of another question: [Way to omit undefined preprocessor branches by default with unifdef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491555/way-to-omit-undefined-preprocessor-branches-by-default-with-unifdef)

Answer (score 1):

Oh, this is the same task as I had in the past. I've tried cpp **unifdef** and **coan** tools - all of them stumbled upon special C# preprocessor things like **#region**. In the end I've decided to make my own one:
https://github.com/gaDZella/undefine.

The tool has a pretty simple set of options compared to the mentioned cpp tools but it is fully compatible with C# preprocessor syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use g++ **-E** option to stop after preprocessing stage

> **-E** -> stop after the preprocessing stage.The output is in the form of preprocessed source code, which is sent to the standard output

Comment: "..but cpp appears to remove #region", does g++ leave it alone?

Comment: @user2864740, region is specific to vc++ compiler right? are you using vc++ to compile?

Comment: `#region` is a directive supported by C#, so stripping it may be problematic if wishing to analyze C# files. (I'm not the one asking the question.)